# how to set a cell to 0 if its blank and another cell has data

Tags: excel, vba

so i have this code and what i want to do is the following:

if `Range("aj61:aj432")` is blank and `Range("F61:F432")` has text, then set the blank cells to 0

Here is what I tried but got a type mismatch

```
Sub Insert_0()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("AJ61:AJ432")
    If IsEmpty(rng) And rng.Offset(-30, 0) <> "" Then rng.Value = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Give us the exact error in a `snippet` please

Comment: `IsEmpty` will always return false for initialized variables

Comment: Are you speaking of truly blank cells or cells with formulas that return `""`?

Comment: the error is: Run-time error '13':-Type Mismatch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use SpecialCells to capture the rows from text values in column F intersecting with the blank values in column AJ.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Insert_0()

    Dim rng As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Intersect(Range("F61:F432").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).EntireRow, _
                        Range("AJ61:AJ432").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks))
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng = 0
    Else
        Debug.Print Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
        On Error GoTo -1
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Super clever use of `INTERSECT()` *(+1)*

Comment: Nice use of `INTERSECT`with `SpecialCells`. Never seen it before

Answer (score 3):

You need to loop through range:

```
For i = 61 To 432
    If Cells("AJ" & i).Value = "" And Cells("F" & i).Value <> "" Then Cells("AJ" & i).Value = 0
Next
```

Comment: got an error: Run-time error '5':Invalid procedure call or argument on the if cells line

Answer (score 1):

no loops

```
Sub Insert_0()
    Intersect(Range("F61:F432").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).EntireRow, Range("AJ:AJ")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a range of multiple cells is blank, you need to use something like:

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) = 0 Then
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to loop through the cells in the range. Something like:

```
dim cel as range
for each cel in rng.cells
    If IsEmpty(cel) And cel.Offset(-30, 0) <> "" Then cel.Value = 0
next
```

to make it faster you could fill an array with the values of the range

Comment: got an error when i ran your code, so i added this after the dim command: set cel = Range("AJ61:AJ432") and the error is: Run-time error '424': Object required.